# Show that subspace is compact

Tags: general-topology

We are given the real line with the topology $T$ in which an open set $S$ is open in the ordinary Euclidean topology and such that $S = -S$, where $-S = \{x|-x\in S\}$. Now you're supposed to show that the subset $[-1,1)$ is a compact subspace of $\mathbb{R}$ in this topology.

In the solution to this problem, they do the following: 
Suppose that $U_i$, $i\in I$ is an open cover of $[-1,1)$ in this topology. Since one of the sets $U_i$ contains $-1$, it must by definition also contain $1$. That is, the set of all $U_i$ covers $[-1,1]$. But this is a compact, so there is a finite subcover of $[-1,1]$, which then also covers $[-1,1)$ and thus $[-1,1)$ must be compact.

I don't see why this is necessary. Why isn't it enough to conclude that e.g. $(-2,2)$, which is an open set in the relevant topology, contains $[-1,1)$ and thus covers it?

Comment: If this was a valid argument then every subset of the real line would be compact since it is covered by the open set $(-\infty,+\infty)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be compact, you require that **any** open cover has a finite subcover.

In your final statement you give just one cover $(-2,2)$. Note how the argument of the previous paragraph works for any open cover $U_i$.

Answer (score 2):

But how would that help you? The meaning of compact set is not that there is some finite open cover of this set (otherwise any topological space $X$ would be compact, because $X$ itself is open and trivially covers the whole space) but that **any** open cover has a finite subcover.